# Android Studio upload video to server

Tags: android, http, video, upload

Does anyone have a decent up-to-date tutorial on how to upload videos to a server using android studio.

Much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is an example of a background task to upload a video to a server. There is nothing Android Studio specific about it - it should work whether your IDE is Eclipse or Studio (or anything else...).

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class VideoUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    /* This Class is an AsynchTask to upload a video to a server on a background thread
     * 
     */

    private VideoUploadTaskListener thisTaskListener;
    private String serverURL;
    private String videoPath;

    public VideoUploadTask(VideoUploadTaskListener ourListener) {
        //Constructor
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","constructor");

        //Set the listener
        thisTaskListener = ourListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Upload the video in the background
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","doInBackground");

        //Get the Server URL and the local video path from the parameters
        if (params.length == 2) {
            serverURL = params[0];
            videoPath = params[1];
        } else {
            //One or all of the params are not present - log an error and return
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","One or all of the params are not present");
            return -1;
        }


        //Create a new Multipart HTTP request to upload the video
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);

        //Create a Multipart entity and add the parts to it
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Building the request for file: " + videoPath);
            FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
            StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename:" + videoPath);
            StringBody description = new StringBody("Test Video");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
            reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
            reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","UnsupportedEncodingException error when setting StringBody for title or description");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        //Send the request to the server
        HttpResponse serverResponse = null;
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Sending the Request");
            serverResponse = httpclient.execute( httppost );
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ClientProtocolException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Check the response code
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Checking the response code");
        if (serverResponse != null) {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ServerRespone" + serverResponse.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity responseEntity = serverResponse.getEntity( );
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                //log the response code and consume the content
                Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","responseEntity is not null");
                try {
                    responseEntity.consumeContent( );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Log the (further...) error...
                    Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOexception consuming content");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        } else {
            //Log that response code was null
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","serverResponse = null");
            return -1;
        }

        //Shut down the connection manager
        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( ); 
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //Check the return code and update the listener
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask onPostExecute","updating listener after execution");
        thisTaskListener.onUploadFinished(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: can this be done with loopj android-async-http library?

Comment: I personally have not used but there is no reason why not. If you are choosing a HTTP library today it probably also makes sense to look at Volley and Retrofit.